# how to response to the server ping in tornado websocket

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have written a websocket server in tornado and i used `websocket_ping_interval=60` to detect which connection is really closed after 60 sec. but after 60 sec the server disconnects the link(even if it's been disconnected). i think this is done because the server sends a ping packet each 60sec and the client doesn't response to the server. i want the client side(which is written in `websocket` python module) to response the server whenever the server sends ping req.
I have the same problem with client websocket in browsers. any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado's websocket implementation handles pings automatically (and so do most other implementations). You shouldn't have to do anything.

Tornado's ping timeout defaults to 3 times the ping interval, so if you're getting cut off after 60 seconds instead of 180 seconds, something else is doing it. Some proxies have a 60-second timeout for idle connections, so if you're going through one of those you may need a shorter ping interval.

If that's not it, you'll need to provide more details, ideally a reproducible test setup with client and server code.

Comment: i don't use proxy. assume i made 60000 connections. the server tells me 60000 connections were established but when i close them all from the client, it seems `on_close` isn't fired 60000 times(seems the server can't detect some of closed connection). and i make a mistake in connection calculations. but when i use ping setting (assume interval=200-sec) after 200 sec `on_close` would be called 60000 times precisely and every things gonna be ok.